# No ID parameter in model save controller when saving after edit

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, save

I've written a model object and I cannot edit and save an existing object, a new object is always created. I can create and delete, but editing doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that this is because the "profile_id" parameter isn't in the request when I save the object.

The interesting thing is that the "profile_id" parameter is in the request when I edit an object, it's just not getting passed to my save controller. `$profile_id` is always 0. Here's the code in my save controller.

```
$profileId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('profile_id');
        $profile = $this->_profileFactory->create();
        if ($profileId) {
            $profile->load($profileId);
        }
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('profile', $profile);
        return $profile;
```

Comment: What is returned by the `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`?

Comment: getParams() returns everything in the form except the profile_id. (key, active_tab, form_key, name, etc.)

Comment: In my edit controller, getParams() returns the profile_id and key.

Comment: For a test, I created the same profile form using a UI component in my layout xml file with a datasource, and saving after editing works. The profile_id is in the request.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I don't need to have a datasource for model objects if I use blocks instead of UI components?

Comment: Yes, you can set data in the block directly.

Comment: As another test, I've tried using the registry to pass the profile_id from the edit controller to the save controller, but it didn't work. The registry is empty in the save controller, which makes sense because the registry object only exists for the current request.

Comment: Sure. You should check is the hidden field with a name `profile_id` exists in your edit form.

Comment: Thanks Siarhey. How do you check for a hidden field? Is it different than calling $this->getRequest()->getParams()?

Comment: Try to find it in your block (form), it should look like `if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('profile_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'profile_id']);
        }` If there is no id-field, just add it to the form, clean cache and check params inside controller.

Comment: I am facing this issue, but i have UI component form
@Joseph Hovik have you find solution?

Comment: @ChiragPatel, I didn't find a solution. I just worked around not having the ID.